# AJAX Form Update for a single Field

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm trying to implement [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) for my Form. For this is need to find a way to update the entity on a **single-property-basis**. The biggest headache this is giving me is the way of how a single data could be validated. To my understanding the `setValidationGroup()` doesn't appear to work (or i am doing this completely wrong). Here's what i tried:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $filters = $form->getInputFilter();
        $filters->setValidationGroup(
            $this->params()->fromPost('name')
        );
        $form->setInputFilter($filters);
    }
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $objectManager->flush();
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $response = $this->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);

            return $response;
        }
    } else {
        $errors = $form->getMessages();
        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($errors);
        die("notvalid");
    }
}
```

The checks for `isXmlHttpReqiest` serve the purpose of **#1** to minify the validation-group to just one Element and **#2** to send out specific responses that work with the x-editable plugin for jQuery.

**Current Error:** all FormFields are validated. I get an error-message for two required fields whose `isEmpty`-Validator are called.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you're calling `setValidationGroup` is wrong Sam, it's a form method, and you give it an array of field names

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $form->setValidationGroup(array(
        'name',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Actually that is not the case. You have two ways of defining the group, one is array, another is a number or string parameters `setValidationGroupd('eOne', 'eTwo', 'eN')`

Comment: Yes, my thrust was more about using the forms method as opposed to the input filters one, rather than the actual param format, but I see from the answer that it would have made no difference.

Comment: Ah yes, you're true on that one, didn#t really notice that. Final example uses the forms one as you mentioned, too!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution was**:

Learn to freaking set your inputFilters correctly. I don't know why i didn't get any parsing error, but there was a string error while fetching the correct inputFilters, so actually there was no inputFilter attached at all.

Since the Form has valid default data, error only occured when validating single elements.

**Essence**:

Start writing Unit Tests ....